# Typescript angularjs $http get response type (avoid use of <any>)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I want to avoid the use of `<any>` in my typescript angularjs code.
Therefor I would like to know if someone knows which class type should be used for the $http get/post/etc. response?

Example: In following piece of code I would like the `<any>` to be class typed instead

```
search() {
    this.$http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {params: {address: this.$scope.searchTerm}})
    .success((response: any) => {
        this.$scope.results = response.results;
    }).error((response: any) => {
        console.error("Error calling the server");
      });
    };
```

P.S.:

this.$scope = MyScopeInterface and this.$scope.results = google.maps.GeocoderResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to type it manually. Typescript's type inference should be able to determine the return type of `.get()` and the type of your `response` parameter accordingly.

In case it isn't, the type is `IHttpPromise<T>`. You can find more details on the [angular.d.ts type declaration](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/angular/index.d.ts)

Comment: I'm writing and compiling my code in Webstorm. Seems this compiler isn't able to determine the return type (Error:(77, 40) TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type '{}'.). Still trying to figure out then in my case, what should <T> be (?)

Comment: `IHTTPPromise<T>` extends `IPromise<IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>>` which means that it's a promise containing an http response arg which is itself containing some data `<T>` as the payload. `<T>` is the type of that payload, so whatever is being returned from the server. [The geocoding api page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses) has an example JSON response. You could construct an interface to match that object, or someone else may have already in a geocoding access library.

Comment: I did, solved my issue: 

`/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

module Services {

  export interface IGeocoder {
    results: google.maps.GeocoderResult[];
    status: google.maps.GeocoderStatus;
  }
  
}`

Comment: Please, update answer:
New repo is: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/angular/index.d.ts
$http methods such $http.get will return IHttpPromise that take in input a function that has IHttpResponse as parameter

Comment: Thank you, @Lemmy4555. Updated.